# CKEditor: MS Edge: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'specified' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jsp, ckeditor, microsoft-edge

Getting a SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'specified' of undefined or null reference when running in JSP on Edge (IE11) whenever I click many buttons such as bold or underline.  No problem in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` on top of the page.

Answer (score -1):

I actually have the same error. I realize that my page was running in quirks mode. Please try to make your page in strict mode so CKEditor would be properly supported for IE11 and Edge.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I have since solved the problem.  I was missing a plug-in.  I'm surprised nobody else responded.

Comment: @Tony, what happens when you use .asp page? and used the basic script tag to replace textarea into CKeditor? It would be great if you can share a working code example. Thanks.